# Executing spring web flow transitions using javascript form submit

Tags: spring-webflow-2, jsf-1.2

We are using a combination of facelets and spring web flow in our web project. There are some variables declared in the web flow. I would like to access these variables outside the flow. The reason I am trying to access these variable is, we are submitting a form using javaScript. We cannot submit a form as part of webflow using javaScript.

Can anybody give directions to submit a form using javaScript and still be part of web flow (as if a commandButton or commandLink was clicked)?

OR

How can I access flow variables outside the we flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the solution after doing some more search on google. I was able to submit a form from javascript and still be part of the web flow. I followed the below steps:

1. Javascript - form submit on change of combo-box value:

   ```
   jQ161("#comboBoxId").change(function(e) {
       var formAction = document.myform.action;
       document.myform.action = formAction + '&_eventId=showDetails&param1=value1';
       document.myform.submit();
   });
   ```

   The *eventId* is set to value of the *transition* in the web flow.
2. We need to have a JSF Phase listener. This listener intercepts in the JSF flow and divert the flow to web flow executor. I needed the flow to be intercepted after the *Update Model Values* JSF phase is completed. Following is the code for the same:

   ```
   import javax.el.ELContext;
   import javax.el.MethodExpression;
   import javax.faces.component.UICommand;
   import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
   import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
   import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
   import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;
   import javax.faces.event.PhaseListener;

   import org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfUtils;

   public class EventIdPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

   public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
       if (JsfUtils.isFlowRequest()) {
           FacesContext context = event.getFacesContext();
           if (context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().containsKey("_eventId")) {
           UICommand eventSource = new UICommand();
           eventSource.setTransient(true);
           eventSource.setParent(context.getViewRoot());
           eventSource.setId("_eventId");
           String eventId = (String) context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("_eventId");
           eventSource.setActionExpression(convertEventIdToMethodExpression(context, eventId));
           context.getViewRoot().queueEvent(new ActionEvent(eventSource));
       }
   }
   }

   public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
       // Do Nothing
   }

   public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
       return PhaseId.UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES;
   }

   private MethodExpression convertEventIdToMethodExpression(FacesContext facesContext, String eventId) {
   ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
   return facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(elContext, eventId,
           String.class, new Class[0]);
   }
   }
   ```

For further details check [JSF Phase Listener](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?65142-Javascript-Form-Submission-SWF-2-amp-JSF&p=219358#post219358) and [Spring web flow and MVC integration](http://www.ervacon.com/products/swf/intro/index.html).